# Xceed datagrid - Get current data

Tags: c#, xceed, xceed-datagrid

I've got an 'XceedDataGridWrapper' in an application which is bound to some data. In the C# file behind the XAML for the file which holds my dataset I have a variable which holds a reference to the Xceed data-grid:

```
public XceedDataGridWrapper GridWrapper;
```

Is there a simple method of getting all of the content that is currently visible on the grid (so if a user applies a filter of some kind, it will return only the items that are being shown)?

In the ideal world I'd like to be able to something similar to this:

```
var dataContext = GridWrapper.CurrentItems;
```

But I don't clearly see a method anywhere to do that.

Help is appreciated!

Comment: Look into `MVVM` and `CollectionViewSource`.

Comment: Would you be able to give any pointers on how to use CollectionViewSource? We already have an MVVM setup.

Comment: But you need to grasp MVVM, because what you want to do in your _ideal world_ line of code sample, doesn't fit that. As for `CollectionViewSource` there's plenty of samples/tutorials out there, just search it.

Comment: It's a semi-MVVM setup, we all understand MVVM but the previous programmers who made the project didn't uncouple everything from the UI. I'm currently only testing, but I just want to be able to quickly get the visible data from the grid. - I'll look into CollectionViewSource

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that 'XceedDataGridWrapper' has a 'CollectionViewSource' in it (thanks for the pointer @jsanalytics), however it was stored in a private property called 'mviewsource'
So what I did was expose it as a dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty CurrentDataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register(
            "CurrentData",
            typeof(DataGridCollectionView),
            typeof(XceedDataGridWrapper),
            new UIPropertyMetadata(null));

public DataGridCollectionView CurrentData
{
    get { return mviewSource; }
}
```

And then I could access the 'CollectionView' from outside the 'XceedDataGrid'.

Comment: I have to wait 2 days until I can accept my own response as the official answer :p